# How to extrapolate matrix valued functions on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods, spline, extrapolation

I have a matrix valued function which I'm trying to find its limit as x goes to 1.

So, in this example, I have three matrices v1-3, representing respectively the sampled values at [0.85, 0.9, 0.99]. What I do now, which is quite inefficient, is the following:

```
for i=1:101
 for j = 1:160
  v_splined = spline([0.85,0.9,0.99], [v1(i,j), v2(i,j), v3(i,j)], [1]);
 end
end
```

There must be a better more efficient way to do this. Especially when soon enough I'll face the situation where v's will be 4-5 dimensional vectors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Naively extrapolating is risky business, do so at your own risk

Here's what I would say

1. Using a spline to extrapolate is risky business and not generally recommended. Do you know anything about the behavior of your function near x=1?
2. In the case where you only have 3 points you're probably better off using a 2nd order polynomial (a parabola) rather than fitting a spline through the three points. (unless you have a good reason not to do this.)
3. If you want to use a parabola (or higher order interpolating polynomial when you have more points), you can vectorize your code and use [Lagrange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) or [Newton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) polynomials to perform the extrapolation which will probably give you a nice speed up.
4. Using interpolating polynomials will also generalize easily to higher order polynomials with more points given. However, this will make extrapolation even more risky since high-order interpolating polynomials tend to oscillate severely near the ends of the domain.

If you want to use Lagrange polynomials to form a parabola, your result is given by:

```
v_splined = v1*(1-.9)*(1-.99)/( (.85-.9)*(.85-.99) ) ...
           +v2*(1-.85)*(1-.99)/( (.9-.85)*(.9-.99) ) ...
           +v3*(1-.85)*(1-.9)/( (.99-.85)*(.99-.9) );
```

I left this un-simplified so you can see how it comes from the Lagrange polynomials, but obviously simplifying is easy. Also note that this eliminates the need for loops.

Comment: Hi Doug, thnx for the help. Here are some answers to your questions:

Comment: Here are some answers to your questions: (1) near x=1 some of the values in the matrix become infinite (mathematically speaking) as it is a singular solution of the NLS (2) This is why i'm not into "forcing" the extrapolation to a Parabola. I can generate more points, but they will all be smaller then 0.995, where my simulation already breaks.

Comment: Even if you don't use a parabola, the spline function is "forcing" a cubic polynomial. Additionally, adding more points away from x=1  has relatively little effect on spline behavior near x=1 and your extrapolation will be almost entirely determined by the three points nearest to 1 and the boundary condition you choose (e.g. natural, not-a-knot, prescribed slope). Without some knowledge of the functional behavior near x=1 I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure there is a singularity at x=1, then interpolate/approximate the pairs (x,y*(x-1)) linearly or quadratically to get the numerator of p(x)/(x-1).

Comment: @LutzL That is of course assuming that the singularity is a first order pole. It may be a higher order pole or a different type of singularity.